# После компиляции проекта, при помощи Gulp, не отображаются некоторые стили и все шрифты

Tags: javascript, frontend, gulp, шрифты

третий день ломаю голову над проблемой - после компиляции проекта при помощи Gulp - не отображаются все шрифты (проблема в том, что они копируются в папку билда dist (woff и woff2 с приставкой fonts**.woff/woff2), чего не должно быть, поскольку они должны размещаться в dist/fonts, но так же woff2 копируется в необходимую папку fonts.

**gulpfile.js:**

```
import gulp from "gulp";

import { path } from "./gulp/config/path.js";

import { plugins } from "./gulp/config/plugins.js";

global.app = {
    isBuild: process.argv.includes('--build'),
    isDev: !process.argv.includes('--build'),
    path: path,
    gulp: gulp,
    plugins: plugins
}

import { copy } from "./gulp/tasks/copy.js";
import { reset } from "./gulp/tasks/reset.js";
import { html } from "./gulp/tasks/html.js";
import { server } from "./gulp/tasks/server.js";
import { scss } from "./gulp/tasks/scss.js";
import { js } from "./gulp/tasks/js.js";
import { images } from "./gulp/tasks/images.js";
import { ttfToWoff, fontsStyle } from "./gulp/tasks/fonts.js";
// import { fonts } from "./gulp/tasks/fonts.js";
import { zip } from "./gulp/tasks/zip.js";
import { ftp } from "./gulp/tasks/ftp.js";

function watcher() {
    gulp.watch(path.watch.files, copy)
    gulp.watch(path.watch.html, html)
    gulp.watch(path.watch.scss, scss)
    gulp.watch(path.watch.js, js)
    gulp.watch(path.watch.images, images)
}

const fonts = gulp.series(ttfToWoff, fontsStyle);

const mainTasks = gulp.series(fonts, gulp.parallel(copy, html, scss, js, images));

const dev = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, gulp.parallel(watcher, server));
const build = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks);
const deployZIP = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, zip);
const deployFTP = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, ftp);

export {dev}
export {build}
export {deployZIP}
export {deployFTP}

gulp.task('default', dev);
```

**path.js:**

```
import * as nodePath from 'path';
const rootFolder = nodePath.basename(nodePath.resolve());

const buildFolder = `./dist`;
const srcFolder = `./src`;

export const path = {
    build: {
        js: `${buildFolder}/js/`,
        css: `${buildFolder}/css/`,
        html: `${buildFolder}/`,
        images: `${buildFolder}/img/`,
        fonts: `${buildFolder}/fonts/`,
        files: `${buildFolder}/files/`
    },
    src: {
        js: `${srcFolder}/js/app.js`,
        images: `${srcFolder}/img/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,gif}`,
        svg: `${srcFolder}/img/**/*.svg`,
        scss: `${srcFolder}/scss/style.scss`,
        html: `${srcFolder}/*.html`,
        files: `${srcFolder}/files/**/*.*`
    },
    watch: {
        js: `${srcFolder}/js/**/*.js`,
        scss: `${srcFolder}/scss/**/*.scss`,
        html: `${srcFolder}/**/*.html`,
        images: `${srcFolder}/img/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,svg,gif,ico}`,
        files: `${srcFolder}/files/**/*.*`
    },
    clean: buildFolder,
    buildFolder: buildFolder,
    srcFolder: srcFolder,
    rootFolder: rootFolder,
    ftp: 'test'
}
```

**fonts.js:**

```
import fs from "fs";
import fonter from "gulp-fonter";
import ttf2woff2 from "gulp-ttf2woff2";

export const ttfToWoff = () => {
  return app.gulp.src(`${app.path.srcFolder}/fonts/*.{ttf, woff, woff2}`)
    .pipe(
      app.plugins.plumber(
        app.plugins.notify.onError({
          title: "FONTS",
          message: "Error: <%= error.message%>",
        })
      )
    )
    .pipe(fonter({
          formats: ['woff', 'ttf']
        }))
    .pipe(app.gulp.dest(`${app.path.build.fonts}`))
    .pipe(app.gulp.src(`${app.path.srcFolder}/fonts/*.ttf`))
    .pipe(ttf2woff2())
    .pipe(app.gulp.dest(`${app.path.build.fonts}`));
};

export const fontsStyle = () => {
  let fontsFile = `${app.path.srcFolder}/scss/_fonts.scss`;
  fs.readdir(app.path.build.fonts, function (err, fontsFiles) {
    if (fontsFiles) {
      if (!fs.existsSync(fontsFile)) {
        fs.writeFile(fontsFile, '', cb);
        let newFileOnly;
        for (let i = 0; i < fontsFiles.length; i++) {
          let fontFileName = fontsFiles[i].split('.')[0];
          if (newFileOnly !== fontFileName) {
            let fontName = fontFileName.split('-')[0]
              ? fontFileName.split('-')[0]
              : fontFileName;
            let fontWeight = fontFileName.split('-')[1]
              ? fontFileName.split('-')[1]
              : fontFileName;
            if (fontWeight.toLowerCase() === "thin") {
              fontWeight = 100;
            } else if (fontWeight.toLowerCase() === "extralight") {
              fontWeight = 200;
            } else if (fontWeight.toLowerCase() === "light") {
              fontWeight = 300;
            } else if (fontWeight.toLowerCase() === "medium") {
              fontWeight = 500;
            } else if (fontWeight.toLowerCase() === "semibold") {
              fontWeight = 600;
            } else if (fontWeight.toLowerCase() === "bold") {
              fontWeight = 700;
            } else if (
              fontWeight.toLowerCase() === "extrabold" ||
              fontWeight.toLowerCase() === "heavy"
            ) {
              fontWeight = 800;
            } else if (fontWeight.toLowerCase() === "black") {
              fontWeight = 900;
            } else {
              fontWeight = 400;
            }
            fs.appendFile(
              fontsFile,
              `@font-face{\n\t font-family: ${fontName};\n\t font-display: swap;\n\t src: url("../fonts/${fontFileName}.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/${fontFileName}.woff") format("woff");\n\t font-weight: ${fontWeight};\n\t font-style: normal; \n}\r\n`,
              cb
            );
            newFileOnly = fontFileName;
          }
        }
      } else {
        console.log(
          "Файл scss/fonts.scss уже существует. Для обновления файла нужно его удалить!"
        );
      }
    }
  });
  return app.gulp.src(`${app.path.srcFolder}`);
  function cb() {}
};
```

**Итог компиляции:**

[image: dist после компиляции]

Перепробовал множество вариантов, но результат практически один и тот же - шрифты не подключаются к проекту, некоторые стили (background-color) не отображаються.

[image: подключение стилей style.scss для style.min.css]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: вы с мака? если да, то тут все понятно)

Comment: все верно, с мака) в чем же проблема?